# Editable HTML table cell that doesn't resize when editing

Tags: css, angularjs, html-table

I'm trying to implement a table with editable cells using an approach like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zwpesm4m/3/). The cell contains a label or span and also an input box, and I'm using a flag to decide which one to display via ng-show. But when the label is made visible, the cell expands vertically. It's subtle in that demo but you can see the second row moving down slightly.

How can I make it remain the same size, like the editable table rows in [this](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row) example? I've looked at the styles in that example but I can't figure out how it's being done. The span for non-edit mode seems to have the dimensions as 'auto' but when the input form appears, it has explicit width/height - and they happen to be exactly the same.

PS. I'm open to the idea that the way I'm doing it isn't optimal, in which case any alternative suggestions would be great.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label ng-click="editing=true" ng-show="!editing">{{ mytext }}</label>
        <input ng-blur="editing=false" ng-show="editing" ng-model="mytext" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>some more text</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's happening because of the border on the `input`. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/zwpesm4m/4/) of the label compensating for it with a little css. Also, in the other example you provided, the element always remains a span and doesn't switch to an input, hence it not bouncing around.

Comment: Thanks @Drew . But I still don't understand how that other example (x-editable) works. It looks like when you click the edit button, they're actually adding the input element to the DOM that that point. In my app I tried using a span for the display text and a bootstrap "form-control" input just like that example (except I'm not adding it on the fly, just using ng-show). But the input makes the cell way bigger when I show it. If x-editable has some styling trick that stops that from happening, I can't see what it is. Maybe it has to do with the fact that they're adding it to the DOM...

Answer (score 0):

I found out why the cells don't expand in the xeditable example that I linked to in my question - it's because there's an explicit size set in the css:

```
div[ng-controller] table tr td {
  height: 45px;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I didn't find this at first because I was looking in the css file that comes with the package, and I couldn't find any rules in there that would explain it. But it's actually defined in another css file for the demo page itself (https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/docs/css/docs.css).